# The package Npgsql with version 4.0.5 could not be found

Tags: visual-studio, jenkins, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I am trying to build a solution on my jenkins pipeline using MSBuild. Here are the stages :

1. Checkout
2. Restore Nuget Packages
3. Build

Here is the script of my pipeline for the part related to nuget packages :

```
environment {
        nuget = "C:/nuget.exe"
    }
stages {
        stage('Restore Nuget Packages') {
            steps {
                script {
                       bat '%nuget% restore "./trunk/BALANCE/TakK_BAL.sln\"'
                       }
                       
        }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                       bat "\"${tool 'MSBuild'}\\MSBuild.exe\" \"./trunk/BALANCE/TakK_BAL.sln\" /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=\"x64\" "
                       }
                       
        }
        }
```

The **checkout** and **restore nuget package** stages are successful but I am getting an error in the **build** stage saying :

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\17.0\Microsoft.NuGet.targets(198,5): 
error : The package Npgsql with version 4.0.5 could not be found in 
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\, 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages. 
Run a NuGet package restore to download the package. 
[C:\Users\ramin.bohlouli\.jenkins\workspace\BalanceTestPipeline\trunk\BALANCE\BalanceOptimaConnector\BalanceOptimaConnector.csproj]
```

However , when going to :

```
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\
```

and also

```
%userprofile%\.nuget\packages
```

which is the default folder , the package with the version 4.0.5 is there.

It's worth mentioning that I checked inside the following path in visual studio and saw that for my project the npgsql 4.0.5 was installed.

tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet packages for solution

What could be the reason and the possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem and solved it.
The problem is that when MSBuil tries to compile , it looks into

```
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages
```

which is not based on a x64 platform. So if you use msbuild.exe which is for x64 , the problem is solved.

You can find the x64 version of msbuild.exe in the following path :

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64
```

I spend 1 day on fixing this problem and I thought it's not something that I can take care of! but sometimes big problems have simple answers.